# What is the best place to store module uploaded images

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

I am creating a module that allows to create some objects and upload images for them.

For the moment, I am uploading images in the module folder itself. But I think it is better to store them in PS `img` folder like for product and category images. One of the reasons is to avoid their deletion when module is deleted mistakenly from backoffice.

Is there any other reason to store/ not store images in `img` folder? What is the best place to store a huge number of uploaded images?

Your ideas are much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's better to save your images in the `img` folder. The most important reason for doing this: this route will never be blocked by `robots.txt`.

In my modules, (in order to be more orderly,) I create a folder called "module" and then inside this folder, I create another folder called the `my-module-name`.

`img/modules/my-custom-module/test.jpg`